# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<x>'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, generics, type-conversion

I have this model with three collections of the same model `<AttendeesMeeting>`

**Meeting**

```
[NotMapped]
[Display(Name = "xxxx", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.ReuniaoResources))]
public virtual ICollection<AttendeesMeeting> Required{ get; set; }

[NotMapped]
[Display(Name = "xxx", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.ReuniaoResources))]
public virtual ICollection<AttendeesMeeting> Informed{ get; set; }

[NotMapped]
[Display(Name = "xxxx", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.ReuniaoResources))]
public virtual ICollection<AttendeesMeeting> Optionals{ get; set; }
```

In a method do a get to retrieve some values.

I'd like three of my model objects only receive the 'Login' from the returned values.

```
public Meeting GetReuniaoForEdit(int id)
{
    var model = this.context.Meetings.Find(id);

    var required = context.AttendeesMeeting.Where(x => x.IdReuniao == id && x.TypeAttendee == 1);
    var informed = context.AttendeesMeeting.Where(x => x.IdReuniao == id && x.TypeAttendee == 2);
    var optionals = context.AttendeesMeeting.Where(x => x.IdReuniao == id && x.TypeAttendee == 3);

    if (required.Any() || informed.Any() || optionals.Any())
    {
        //Login is a string
        model.required = required.Select(x => x.Login).ToList();
    }
}
```

Error:

```
model.required = required.Select(x => x.Login).ToList();
```

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   '`System.Collections.Generic.List<string>`' to
>   '`System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<Models.AttendeesMeeting>`'. An
>   explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

How do I turn the string list in a collection of my model?

It's possible?

Comment: What string do you want to return exactly?

Comment: Your `required` property wants a collection of meetings, you're giving it a list of strings. Either change it to `model.required = required.ToList();` or update your property to be `ICollection<string>`

Comment: If you only want the `Login` then why is your property a collection of `AttendeesMeeting` instead of `string`?  It's not clear on exactly what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I don't change ICollection<AttendeesMeeting>  for ICollection<string>. Use this in other locations.

Answer (score 2):

Right now, by `.Select(x => x.Login).ToList()` you create a list of strings that you want to assign to a `ICollection<AttendeesMeeting>`. You can solve this in several ways, for instance:

- You can **change the model**, so that `ICollection<AttendeesMeeting>` is substituted by `ICollection<string>`. If you ever only need the `Login`, then your model should be optimized for that.
- You can leave out `.Select(x => x.Login)` and by that assign the collection of meetings to the property in the model; in your view, you **only show the `Login` property** of the model and leave out the rest of the data.
- If you cannot change the existing model, I'd propose to **create a new model class** that stores exactly the data you need in the special case. In this case, you'd add the properties as `ICollection<string>` to the new model and use this in the special case.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you want is get the meetings by their `login`. Thus you need a further step as `required.Select(x => x.Login).ToList()` will only select the logins of your meetings. However you need to further select all those meetings that fit those IDs:

```
var model = this.context.Meetings.Where(x => required.Select(y => y.Login).Contains(x.login));
```

Comment: Login is AttendeesMetting not Meeting :*

Comment: Within your source-code you say that `login` is a string.